# Vite: ?inline not working as expected when loading css for TinyMCE

Tags: laravel, tinymce, vite

I am implementing self hosted TinyMCE in my application.

I am referring [this](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react/discussions/182?sort=new#discussioncomment-203737) link for the implementation. Here is my code

```
/* TinyMCE scripts loading here. All good! */
import contentUiCss from 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.css?inline';
import contentCss from 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css?inline';

tinymce.init({
    selector: '#my_text_area',
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright',
    placeholder: 'Write your text here',
    skin: false, // skin is loaded manually above as an import
    content_css: false, // loaded manually directly below
    content_style: [contentCss, contentUiCss].join('\n'),
});
```

The contents from `content.css` and `contentUiCss` are also getting injected in my `<head>` section which is causing the css conflicts.

As per the [fix](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3246) of Vite, it should not happen this way. Where am I getting wrong?

**Vite version: 3.1.0**

PS: Tried with `?raw` as well but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

This is not because of Vite but because of TinyMCE. As per the documentation of [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/add-css-options/#content_style)

> In inline mode, it (CSS provided) is injected into the head of the page TinyMCE is rendered in.

**Fix for this:**

You do not need `tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css`. The code works perfectly fine even without it (At least as of now)

For the other one, we have a file in the oxide folder for inline mode: `tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.inline.css`

So, the updated working code is:

```
import contentUiCss from 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.inline.css?inline';

tinymce.init({
    selector: '#my_text_area',
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright',
    placeholder: 'Write your text here',
    skin: false, // skin is loaded manually above as an import
    content_css: false, // loaded manually directly below
    content_style: contentUiCss,
});
```

And it's all good to go!

Hope it helps someone! :)